# Why would the function 'time' as defined in time.h return NULL?

Tags: c, ansi-c, time.h

I've got code that uses the function 'time' and other functions from 'time.h', and 'time' returns NULL every 'time' (haha although not funny, this is expensive on 'time' available for me to focus attention towards such) such is re-executed. It is strange in the fact that this only began yesterday. Previous usage of the same function in similar but lacking (I've been adding to it) code proved okay. The following is the C89 code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1

typedef struct tm tm;

int logf(char input_string[])
{
    time_t* current_time_since_epoch;
    time(current_time_since_epoch);
    if (current_time_since_epoch == NULL)
    {
        printf("'time' returned NULL.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    tm* current_time_calandar_time = localtime(current_time_since_epoch);
    if (current_time_calandar_time == NULL)
    {
        printf("'localtime' returned NULL.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char current_time_textual_representation[20];
    strftime(current_time_textual_representation, 20, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", current_time_calandar_time);
    printf("%s\n", current_time_textual_representation);
    printf("%s\n", input_string);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void)
{
    int check_logf = logf("Hello.");
    if (check_logf == 0) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    else
    {
        printf("'logf' returned EXIT_FAILURE.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: `stdlib.h` has its own `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` definitions (even in C89), and they are portable. However, `EXIT_SUCCESS` is pretty useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for the `time()` function to store the result if you want to provide it as a parameter. Either declare the variable on the stack or call `malloc()`. You can also retrieve the returned value if you give `NULL` as a parameter.

```
time_t current_time_since_epoch;
time(&current_time_since_epoch);
// or
current_time_since_epoch = time(NULL);
// or
time_t* timePtr = (time_t*) malloc(sizeof(time_t));
time(timePtr);
// ...
free(timePtr);
```

More info on the function `time()` prototype [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time)

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Thanks.You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds. Sorry for being a pill.

Comment: No it would not. The function take a pointer to a memory you must have "allocated" first either by explicitely calling malloc() or by using a variable declared on the stack (as I'm doing on the first example). If you give a pointer to something undefined time() will try to write something at a undefined position in the memory, you should not do that.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass the address of a `time_t` to **[`time()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time)** it stores the result at that address. Since you didn't allocate any memory to store the result (all you did was declare an uninitialized pointer), you're getting undefined behavior.  Just pass `NULL` to `time` and it will return the value.

```
time_t current_time_since_epoch = time(NULL);
```